# suitable way to import text file which contain html code into mysql db - specific column

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

May i know what is a suitable way to import text file which contain html code into mySQL db - specific column ?

it is a bunch of html code save in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

load data local infile '/tmp/htmlsd.txt'  into table  lines terminated by '' (HTMLfieldname);

I have figure out a way to load data if we have a single field. But unable to find a way if we have mutiple columns HTML based and non HTML based.
Can you guys please provide a solution.